# How to remove cursor from Textbox (in a progress bar)?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, progress-bar

I used a tutorial from Excel Easy (https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/progress-indicator.html) to create a progress bar (`TextBbox`). I followed the exact steps, but my progress bar has something weird in it.

How can I remove the cursor from it?

([image: progress-bar.png]

How do I get rid of that type cursor-like-thingy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.Enabled` Property to `False`

[image]

> *This obviously goes without saying, that you won't be able to input anything inside the `Textbox`*

Answer (score 1):

You must use Label instead of TextBox

[image]